# Unable to retrieve secure score results for my tenant

Tags: security, office365, reporting

I'm trying out the [Secure Score API](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office365security/using-the-office-365-secure-score-api/)

```
curl -XGET "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getTenantSecureScores(period=1)/content" -H "Authorization: Bearer ..." -H "Content-Type: Application/json"
```

but I'm getting the following error

```
{
"error": {
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": "Resource not found for the segment 'reports'.",
"innerError": {
  "request-id": "ba775602-1e27-43e3-858f-4203801b072d",
  "date": "2017-06-20T10:49:08"
}
```

}

The token I am using has the required set of permissions as mentioned [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office365security/using-the-office-365-secure-score-api/)

```
"roles":["User.ReadWrite.All","Group.ReadWrite.All","Files.ReadWrite.All","Reports.Read.All"]
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

Let's change from v1.0 to beta and your issue is fixed.